# Raspberry Pi 2, repair hardware damage

Tags: pi-2, hardware

I bought two damaged Raspberry Pi 2s. Both don't boot regardless of the SD cards content (SD card is working in different Raspberry Pi). Both LEDs are steadily on.

The previous owner told me that the power source was probably defective, but I don't know, maybe he messed with the GPIO pins or else.

I measured Pins 1 & 2, voltage was 3,3 and 5 as expected.
I can't *see* any defect on the board.

What can I do to further debug this?
I read sometimes D5 is faulty, how can I check this?

Comment: Nobody has found a cost effective way of repairing a Pi.  The simplest, quickest, and cheapest way of getting a working Pi is to buy a new one.

Comment: I read about several cases where D5 was defective, this could be replaced easily.
Despite the cost effectiveness I don't want to just throw them away